# Ag-Grid + Angular + Filtering a complex data

Tags: ag-grid

I have a table using ag-grid in an angular application. I have a column in which a filter needs to be added for it. This column is an Array and it can have multiple records for each record. Please find the attachment. When I filter REPORT 1 , since REPORT 2 is also part of the row, it is getting displayed. Can you please let me know how do I filter to get only REPORT 1 ?

[image]

```
 {
        headerName: 'Available Reports',
        field: 'reportTypes',
        cellRendererFramework: LinkComponentComponent,                        
        width: 1020,        
        filter: "agSetColumnFilter",               
        keyCreator: this.reportKeyCreator  ,  
        filterParams: {          
          cellHeight: 20,
          debounceMs: 1000,             
          selectAllOnMiniFilter: true 
        }                                        
      } 

reportKeyCreator(params) {           
    return params.value[0].reportType;
  }
```

Here is the data structure

```
[
  {
    "Name": "ABCD-126",
    "reportDate": "10-02-2018",
    "reportTypes": [
      {
        "reportType": "REPORT1",
        "reportPath": "report1",
        "reportNum": "114"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "ABCD-126",
    "reportDate": "10-01-2018",
    "reportTypes": [
      {
        "reportType": "REPORT1",
        "reportPath": "report1",
        "reportNum": "115"
      },
      {
        "reportType": "REPORT2",
        "reportPath": "report2",
        "reportNum": "116"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Provide  please your data structure

Comment: Hi, I have provided the data structure. Can you please check ?

Comment: How are you ensuring that you actually get the desired row, when you're only passing in the first report type in the array to the key creator?

Answer (score 1):

You can create own [`customFitler`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/) and handle needed things internally, but 
I suppose you need to split complex object by cells and to get grouped concept you can use [HeaderGroupping](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping-headers/).

It would be a more correct way.

```
{
    headerName: "Reports",
    children: [
        {headerName: "Type", field: "reportType"},
        {headerName: "Path", field: "reportPath"},
        {headerName: "Num", field: "reportNum"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. Actually , I have a requirement to display the data as there in the image. So, I used an agSetColumnFilter and handled things internally but I am facing a small issue. I am not able to get the model of the filter in KeyCreator. Any idea how to get it ?